# Which things should be taken care of in Java Socket Application over DDNS?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client-server, chat

I have developed a Chat Application for two person, one being server another will be client, using **Java Socket Programming.** Every thing was fine till this morning. It was working over **localhost**, **local networks** as well as **On my DDNS** ( My Router is configured to forward **any** traffic on it's port `8888` and `3434` to same port on my IP, which is again **Reserved** in my router ). But now it works strangely. I ran a server on my laptop at port `8888` I tried to connect the client through my **DDNS** on port `8888`, Client shows it is connected, but Server shows it is disconnected. Client even sends message successfully which does not appear in server.

I want to know what causes such strange behaviour of my application, is this my firewall, because I have used my DDNS a lot in order to debug some issue.

I also want to know what **precautions** should one take in order to use **DDNS** in Java Socket.

***Additional Informations:***

1. My DDNS in on [Dynu](https://www.dynu.com/)
2. OS: Windows 7 32 bit
3. Quick Heal Antivirus and firewall (Outdated)
4. I am adding some pictures:

[image: Client shows it is connected][image: Server shows no connection][image: Client sends message successfully to whome god knows]